# Pandas .str.replace not replacing all instances in a table

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I've got a data frame with several instances of `' *Winner*'` after the person's name.  I'd like to remove this so just their name remains.  A simplified version of this is below:

```
Data = {'YEAR': [2020, 2020, 2020],
        'NAME': [ 'Tom *Winner*', 'Dick *Winner*', 'Harry *Winner*']}
df = pd.DataFrame(Data)
df['NAME'] = df['NAME'].str.replace(' [*]Winner[*]', '')
df
```

Which results in this:

```
    YEAR    NAME
0   2020    Tom
1   2020    Dick *Winner*
2   2020    Harry
```

So my question is what is different about Dick's `' *Winner*'` tag vs. the other two?  Why is this one not being removed? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

As an extra confusing note, I just copied my code above and re-ran it (assuming that's how people here might test it) and it does remove Dick's `' *Winner*'` tag.  So something about my original data is different and is stripped out when pasted here.  Not sure how to help reproduce it this being the case.

**Edit:** Per request from @user17242583, here is the result of `df.to_dict()`

```
{'NAME': {0: 'Tom *Winner*', 1: 'Dick\xa0*Winner*', 2: 'Harry *Winner*'},
 'YEAR': {0: 2020, 1: 2020, 2: 2020}}
```

Comment: " So something about my original data is different and is stripped out when pasted here." Then we can't possibly help you with it. "Not sure how to help reproduce it this being the case." What happens when you try using Pandas to extract just the row that causes the problem, and create a dict from it (using `.to_dict` on the resulting DataFrame or Series)?

Comment: As an aside, if you just wanted to match literal `*`s, don't use that kind of regex syntax to escape those symbols; just tell Pandas not to use regex. That said, you've been given an answer which requires regex (based on guessing the actual problem in your data).

Comment: @Ryan can you try adding the output of `df.to_dict()` to the question? I'm curious to see what's the matter with your data.

Comment: @user17242583 just added to the question

Comment: You did `to_dict`, not `to_dict()` ;)

Comment: Whoops there you go.  Sure enough some extra characters there.

Comment: Yep! That's a thin, no-breaking space character very often used in French text. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the placement of the other "\" characters?  Is that just dividing the string into its relevant components that I want to replace?

Comment: Oh sorry @Ryan, I didn't see your last comment! The `\` characters aren't treated as literal `\` characters. They cause a few of the characters that come after to be escaped...read more [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/escape-sequences-python/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```py
df['NAME'] = df['NAME'].str.replace('\s*\*Winner\*', '', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   YEAR   NAME
0  2020    Tom
1  2020   Dick
2  2020  Harry
```

The reason that works is because your data has a `\xa0`, which is a [thin, non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). In your original code, you have a space hardcoded, but my code uses `\s*` which means "0 or more of any whitespace characters," which includes `\xa0` (char code 160).